# Creating a bitmap of a drawn square in android opengl es 2.0

Tags: android, opengl-es, bitmap, opengl-es-2.0, android-bitmap

I have drawn a square using opengl es 2.0 and now i want to create a bitmap of that drawn square. Can anyone please guide me on how to do that? Please let me know if my question is not clear. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is done using glReadPixels().  This is slow, but is the only method available with OpenGL ES 2.0 on Android.  In Java:

```
Bitmap buttonBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mWidth, mHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(mWidth * mHeight * 4);
GLES20.glReadPixels(0, 0, mWidth, mHeight, GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, byteBuffer);
buttonBitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(byteBuffer);
```

However, it is considerably faster if implemented in native code:

```
JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_com_CopyToBitmap(JNIEnv * env, jclass clazz, jobject bitmap)
{
AndroidBitmapInfo   BitmapInfo;
void *              pPixels;
int                 ret;

if ((ret = AndroidBitmap_getInfo(env, bitmap, &BitmapInfo)) < 0)
{
    LOGE("Error - AndroidBitmap_getInfo() Failed! error: %d", ret);
    return JNI_FALSE;
}

if (BitmapInfo.format != ANDROID_BITMAP_FORMAT_RGBA_8888)
{
    LOGE("Error - Bitmap format is not RGBA_8888!");
    return JNI_FALSE;
}

if ((ret = AndroidBitmap_lockPixels(env, bitmap, &pPixels)) < 0)
{
    LOGE("Error - AndroidBitmap_lockPixels() Failed! error: %d", ret);
    return JNI_FALSE;
}

glReadPixels(0, 0, BitmapInfo.width, BitmapInfo.height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pPixels);

AndroidBitmap_unlockPixels(env, bitmap);
return JNI_TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ClayMongomery for the help, there is one more thing i want to know that the bitmap that we get using the above method (using glReadpixels()), will the format of that bitmap be similar to the bitmap that we get when we decodeResource from a drawable using BitmapFactory.decodeResource() method?

Comment: There is one important difference for the GL_RGBA format.  The Bitmap class requires the pre-multiplied alpha format, where R, G and B are scaled by A.  OpenGL does not do that by default, but you can easily add it to your fragment shader with: R * A, G * A, B * A.