# OpenGL ES Offscreen Drawing issue

Tags: android, opengl-es, off-screen

I am using PixelBuffer class decribed here http://www.anddev.org/android-2d-3d-graphics-opengl-tutorials-f2/possible-to-do-opengl-off-screen-rendering-in-android-t13232.html. In my Renderer I use GLU.lookAt to view back face of a 3D object but PixelBuffer does not seem to return the buffer with back face but instead still shows Front face of the object. What might be causing this? Can this issue be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, pbuffers are obsolete and not supported on Android devices with Nvidia Tegra GPUs.  Android has built-in classes for offscreen rendering named TextureView and SurfaceTexture you should use or you can use an FBO.  I have a collection of articles here which will help:

http://montgomery1.com/opengl/

I don't know what OpenGL ES driver you are running, but it probably only supports single-buffered pbuffers, so there is no back buffer.

Back faces is a different concept that depends on the winding direction of your triangles to allow back-face culling.  It has nothing to do with off-screen rendering.

**Update:**

Adding a link to some sample code that shows how to copy a texture image into an Android Bitmap:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22683572/creating-a-bitmap-of-a-drawn-square-in-android-opengl-es-2-0/22693766#22693766
```

Comment: Apologies for bad terminology. I am using Android supporting OpenGL ES1.1. I have a textured cube and by front face I meant face of the cube towards viewer and back face is opposite face away from viewer not visible to him. I am drawing this using a renderer and I set the renderer to PixelBuffer. Reason for doing all this is that I have to show the geometry on App Widgets and App Widgets don't support GLSurfaceView. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: I do a GLU.gluLookAt to show other faces to viewer but pbuffer always returns a bitmap as if gluLookAt call is ignored. When I use same renderer on GLSurfaceView it works fine but same renderer to PixelBuffer does not.

Comment: Even with OpenGL ES 1.1 it is better to use an FBO extension than pbuffers.  Back faces are determined by winding direction, not which way gluLookAt() is pointed.  Back face culling must be enabled too.

Comment: Thank you. Your suggestion about face culling somewhat worked for me and I see the face of the object I want now. I used the think face culling will let me see inner surface of the face instead of outer surface of the face away from viewer. Use of pbuffer also caused another problem where me light direction changed by 180 degrees. Face culling did not resolve that. Need to work on this and use of FBO. Will provide input if I succeed. Last time I checked FBOs were available on iOS but not on android.

Comment: Clay, Lighting issue was because of bug in my program. I was looking at implementing the FBO and read following "Different Android devices support OpenGL ES extensions may be different, so if you need to use applications create FrameBuffer objects need to check whether the phone supports Framebuffer extension". If even FBO not supported on all phones then how would it be different than using PixelBuffer?

Comment: FBOs are required for OpenGL ES 2.0 and 99% of phones have that.  It is only the FBO extension for 1.1 that might not be implemented, but I have not seen one that does not have it.

Comment: Apologies. I am not a graphics programmer. just learning out of interest. I decided to use FrameBufferObjects and so reading about it but not getting much progress. Here are specific questions I have. 1) Is it possible to use FBOs without using GLSurfaceView.Renderer? If yes, how can I get GL11 object. 2) Once my scene is drawn on FBO then how can I read it as Bitmap. Is glReadPixel the option?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  The Android SurfaceTexture class is an abstracted FBO for 2.0. I added a link above to sample code for using glReadPixels(). To create an EGL surface that is off-screen on Android, construct a SurfaceTexture and pass that to eglCreateWindowSurface(). You should also look at using the EGL Image Extension and EGL_NATIVE_BUFFER_ANDROID.

Comment: I tried implementing FBO without using SurfaceTexure since this class was added in API level 11 and I want to support min API level 7 as well. I used eglCreatePbufferSurface and then obtained GL object from eglContext.getGL. Then I obtained GLExtentionPack object and used FrameBuffer.  This works in API level 7 an 8 but when I change API level 14 I get GLError 0x500. Is using eglCreatePbufferSurface equivalent to using PBuffers?

Comment: Yes, that is how you create a pbuffer.  Less than 1% of all Android devices run API 8 or below.  https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html#OpenGL

Comment: Thanks. Since GLExtentionPack is available in API level less than 8 as well then there must be a way to obtain GL object without using SurfaceTexture or PBuffer? Following is what I am doing right now. But I think you are saying this is PBuffer                                                             [code] eglSurface = egl.eglCreatePbufferSurface(eglDisplay, eglConfig, attribList);
    egl.eglMakeCurrent(eglDisplay, eglSurface, eglSurface, eglContext);
        gl10 = (GL11) eglContext.getGL();
        boolean ctxSupportsExt = checkIfContextSupportsFrameBufferObject(gl10);[/code]

Comment: Pbuffer may be your best option for such old APIs.

Comment: I converted my Opengl ES 1.x program to Opengl ES2.0 program. It works fine as activity. Then I tried SurfaceTexture for offscreen drawing. SurfaceTexture API mandates to use GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES bind target in glBindTexture instead of GL_TEXTURE_2D so replace GL_TEXTURE_2D with GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES but now I am getting GL_INVALID_ENUM error in glBindTexture call since it has a target GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES. Khronos docs for glBindTexture has not reference for GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES. Will appreciate your help on this. I could make OPENGLES 2 with PixelBuffer again but Not SurdaceTextur

Comment: Do not use GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES because that is for external textures such as YCrCb color space as from a camera.  The SurfaceTexture class works fine with GL_TEXTURE_2D.  The Google documentation is full of holes and is very misleading.

Comment: Thank you. I used GL_TEXTURE_2D. Right now it only works in emulator and not on device. Also It does not work in emulator if I use a Configuration activity for my widget. It just crashes the emulator. I also used the code suggested by you in another post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22776290/opengl-es-offscreen-drawing-issue. Is initializing with a hardcoded textureId 1(as you used in the post) correct? Is there any significance of that textureID at all? my code works in emulator even if I pass 0 as textureID to SurfaceTexture Constructor.

Comment: The Samsung devices are known for buggy OpenGL ES drivers.  That texture ID should really be generated with glGenTextures().